# Simple node discovery method

Tags: java, akka, distributed, apache-spark, apache-storm

I'm starting work on a system that will need to discover nodes in a cluster and send those nodes jobs to work on. I know that a myriad of systems exist that solve this but I'm unclear about the complexities of each and which would best suit my specific needs.

Our requirements are that an application should be able to send out job requests. Each request will specify multiple segments of data to work on. Nodes in the cluster should get these job requests and figure out whether the data segments being requested are "convenient". The application will need to keep track of which segments are being worked on by some node and then possibly send out a further requests if there are data segments that it needs to force some nodes to work on (all the nodes have access to all the data, but they should prefer to work on data segments that they have already cached).

This is a very typical map/reduce problem but we don't want to use the standard hadoop solutions because we are trying to avoid the overhead of writing preliminary results to files. This is more of a streaming problem where we want nodes to perform filtering on data that they read and then send it over a network socket to the application that will combine the results from all the nodes.

I've taken a quick look at akka, apache-spark (streaming), storm and just plain simple UPNP and I'm not quite sure which one would suit my needs best. One thing that works against at least spark is that it seems to require ZooKeeper to be set up on the network which is a complication that we'd like to be able to avoid.

Is there any simple library that does something similar to this "auto discover nodes via network multicast" and then allows you to simply send messages back and forth to negotiate which node will handle which data segment? Will Akka be able to help me here? How are nodes added/discovered in a cluster there? Again, we'd like to keep the configuration overhead to a minimum which is why UPNP/SSDP look sort of nice.

Any suggestions for how to use the solutions mentioned above or even other libraries or solutions to look into are very much appreciated.

Comment: You described in coarse lines what Spark actually does. What I don't get from your 'job' description is why you are looking at 'streaming' kind of frameworks.

Comment: Basically because the jobs that are executed on the nodes need to read from files. The data segments I mentioned are basically just different files and it's better if a node reads from the same file again and again since the contents will get cached. The only processing that is done is filtering so a node will read a file and throw out lines that don't match the filter criteria but send others through a socket to the aggregator. We don't want intermediate results being written to files with added latency. I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

You could use Akka Clustering: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/java/cluster-usage.html. However, it doesn't use multicast, it uses a Gossip protocol to handle node up/down messages. You could use a Cluster-Aware Router (see the Akka Clustering doc and http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/java/routing.html) to route your messages to the cluster, there are several different types of routers depending on your needs and what you mean by "convenient". If "convenient" just means which actor is currently free, you can use a Smallest Mailbox router. If it has something to do with the content of the message, you could use a Consistent Hashing router.

Comment: Thanks. I looked a bit at Akka clustering and it seems to require some seed nodes to be known. This is a "complication" over just using SSDP/UPnP to "broadcast" a message about a job on the network and see who replies. It may be naive of me to think that I can get away with not having to configure anything and just be able to run something that will "magically" broadcast a message and get replies from nodes that are willing to do work but so far I haven't heard good arguments against that approach.

Answer (score 3):

See [Balancing Workload Across Nodes with Akka 2](http://letitcrash.com/post/29044669086/balancing-workload-across-nodes-with-akka-2).

This post describes a work distribution algorithm using Akka.  The algorithm doesn't use multicast to discover workers.  There is a well-known master address and the workers register with the master.  Other than that though it fits your requirements well.

Another variation on it is described in [Akka Work Pulling Pattern](http://www.michaelpollmeier.com/akka-work-pulling-pattern/).

I've used this pattern in a number of projects - it works great.

Comment: Excellent article. Explains a whole lot for me about Akka and how work is distributed. Thanks! One problem that I see (or more accurately, don't see addressed) with this is the mailboxes being "content aware". That is, the nodes want to work on specific data segments, where should that logic reside? Maybe there's an easy way to solve this by extending the example, I just don't have the experience with Akka to know how it should be done. Another problem is the configuration complexity of having to have a known master as you mention.

Comment: The `WorkerRequestsWork` message could be extended to include the type of work the worker is interested in.  The location of the master is basically a URL, so it could be set as a system property or in a config file (Akka has a nice configuration system).

Answer (score 0):

Storm is fairly resilient when it comes to worker-nodes coming offline & online.  However, just like Spark, it does require Zookeeper.

The good news is that Storm is comes with a sister project to make deployment a breeze: https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm-deploy/wiki

If you're running vanilla storm on EC2, the `storm-deploy` project could be what you're looking for.